# imagemagick in asp.net via command line

Tags: c#

I use Imagemagick in my ASP.NET webproject to generate thumbs via the commandline interface of imagemagick using a System.Diagnostics.Process

When a user visists a site, 20 media items are fetched from the database, and for each an thumb image gets generated, like this:

```
var thumb = media.GetThumb(100, 100);
```

which starts a Process that uses the "convert" command from imagemagick

However, the performance could be better.

I know, caching the thumbs is a good option, and that is exactly what I am going to do.

However, I suspect, that starting a new Process for each image that is not cached is quite expensive. Any better like "reusing" a process or keeping imagemagick in memory and access this instance or what not?

Comment: I'm sure you could get more advanced with memory/process management but I think you already have the right approach, use the costly operation and cache the results. Cycles are cheap, as long as you've eliminated costly operations from occurring on every request that don't have to be that's main optimization that should be done in ASP.NET IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the time it takes for a thumbnail to be generated is not too long, I am right now using just the caching solution. Furthermore, I dont want to add to much complexity to the project - keeping it as simple as possible.

But for future projects I am trying to evaluate if I can start a background thread at the Application_Start Event, which queries the database for 10 images, generates their thumbs and goes on with the next 10 etc. until no more images without thumbnail exist. This seems like a doable approach, although I havent used it in production yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`ImageMagick.NET`](http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/),

> A .NET wrapper of perhaps the greatest image manipulation API there is, `ImageMagick`

Though still in alpha,
it (or the earlier version) might provide the functionality you need.
A very brief look into the [source](http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/changeset/view/34174?projectName=imagemagick) reveals very little functionality, but it might be a start.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I did not know it yet. However, the library seems not (yet) production ready. It might be an option in the future, however.